# Destructor being called on something that was not constructed

Tags: c++, destructor

The following code gives an exception for g++ version 4.6.2, but runs as expected with g++ version 4.2.1.  Messages printed during execution indicate that in both cases a destructor is being called on an address which was never constructed.  I would like to know (a) which of the compilers is correct, (b) why is something being destroyed without being created.  Thanks much.

```
//------------------------------------------------------
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Poly{
 private:
  float *coeff;
 public:
  Poly(){
    coeff = NULL;
    cout << "Created "<< this << endl;
  }
  Poly(Poly const & p){          // copy constructor
    coeff = NULL;
    cout << "Executed copy constructor.\n";
  }
  Poly operator=(Poly const & rhs){
    cout << "Executed assignment. " << this << " = " << &rhs << endl;
  }
  Poly fun(){
    Poly c;
    return c;
  }
  ~Poly(){
    cout << "Destructor: " << this << endl;
    delete[] coeff;
  }
};


main(){
  Poly a;
  a = a.fun();
}
//------------------------------------------------------
```

For g++ 4.6.2 it gives and exception:

```
% ./a.out
Created 0xbfdcc184
Created 0xbfdcc18c
Executed assignment. 0xbfdcc184 = 0xbfdcc18c
Destructor: 0xbfdcc188
*** glibc detected *** free(): invalid pointer: 0xbfdcc1a8 ***
Aborted
```

For g++ 4.2.1 it does the following

```
% ./a.out
Created 0x7fff5fbff930
Created 0x7fff5fbff920
Executed assignment. 0x7fff5fbff930 = 0x7fff5fbff920
Destructor: 0x7fff5fbff910
Destructor: 0x7fff5fbff920
Destructor: 0x7fff5fbff930
```

There is no exception, and with more code it does produce the correct answer.  However, it does seem to be destroying 0x7fff5bff910 which never was constructed.  Note that the copy constructor is never called, it would print a message if it had been.

Comment: Can you please make sure you've posted the exact code that you are working with. `main` without a return type should generate a compile error.

Comment: ...For those who think that calling `delete[]` on `NULL` is incorrect: **"In either alternative [delete and delete[]], if the value of the operand of delete is the null pointer the operation has no effect."**

Answer (score 6):

It looks like your "Poly operator=" does not return anything.

Answer (score 3):

There are two actual errors with your program. The first is that `main` needs to be declared as returning `int`.

The second is that your copy assignment operator is not declared as returning `void` but control leaves the function without executing a `return` statement. This causes *undefined behavior* and hence the unpredictable effects that you are seeing.

---

You almost certainly want your copy assignment operator to return a reference and not an object by value and to `return *this;`. Although technically you could return any `Poly` object by value it would be extremely unconventional.

Obvisouly, your copy constructor and copy assignment operator aren't yet doing any useful copying in the implementation but I assume that this is because the code is for test or "not yet implemented".

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is in assignment operator. It returns `Poly by value`, but you never assign something to it.

So, in this line `a = a.fun();` we get new `Poly` as result of `operator=`. This temporary variable goes out off scope immediately and so it destructor called. But as you do not return something from `operator =`, this temporary was not constructed.

I recommend you turn on all warnings while compiling using `-Wall` argument to `gcc` and return reference from `operator=`, not temporary.

Comment: I like the explanation.  Wow!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Poly is created 3 times `Poly a;` in main. `Poly c;` in `fun()`. and before the result of function is assigned. So there are 3 destructors.

This behaviour is OK, but some compiler may optimise this process.

Comment: I wouldn't call the behaviour of the program isn't OK, there is _undefined behavior_.

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
Poly fun(){
Poly c;
return c;
}
...
Poly a;
a = a.fun();
```

without return value optimization:

1. a is created
2. c is created
3. copy of c is created
4. c is destructed
5. copy of c is assigned into a
6. copy of c is destructed
7. a is destructed

with return value optimization:

1. a is created
2. c is created
3. c is assigned into a
4. c is destructed
5. a is destructed

Also note that `operator=` should look like this:

```
Poly& operator=(const Poly& rhs){
    cout << "Executed assignment. " << this << " = " << &rhs << endl;
    return *this;
}
```

I recommend you to use `std::vector` instead of a simple array. And I also recommend you to use `double` rather than `float`. If you declare `coeff` like this: `std::vector<double> coeff;` then you don't need to allocate memory for it, you don't need to explicitly initialize it and you also don't need to delete it.

Comment: `operator=` should always return a non-const reference for [compatibility with standard containers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969387/why-operator-returns-reference-not-const-reference).