# explicitly-defaulted copy assignment operator must return MyClass &

Tags: c++, c++11, assignment-operator

```
// Task.h
class Task
{
public:
    Task() = default;
    Task(const Task &) = delete;
    ~Task() = default;
    Task(Task &&) = default;
    const Task & operator= (const Task &) = default;
};


/main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Task.h"

int main()
{
    Task t;
    std::cout<<"hello world"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm coding c++ on Mac OS. When I compile the code above: `g++ main.cpp`, I get the error as below:

> error: explicitly-defaulted copy assignment operator must return 'Task
>   &'

I don't understand at all. `operator=` can ONLY return non-const reference here? I executed the same code in Windows and it worked without any error. So Mac OS has some special c++ standard?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why operator= returns reference not const reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969387/why-operator-returns-reference-not-const-reference)

Comment: @dlmeetei  I don't need to know the advantage of non-reference. I need to know why I got an error. Because I executed the same code in Windows and it works very well.

Comment: Remove `const` and itll work, i cant say why at the moment.

Comment: @Yves, What we are trying to say is that it is mandated by C++ standard because of reason mentioned in the post. Not sure though why it compiles on WIndows

Comment: @FilipKočica  Me neither...

Comment: @FilipKočica  I know why. I ll post the answer.

Comment: @Yves: *"We can return const reference to forbid a = b = c"*, We return reference actually to allow that. Returning `void` seems even better if you want to forbid cascade code like `foo(a = b)` or `(a = b).bar()`, but it would not be the *default*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I use `= default`.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment

If `= default` is used, the type of return must be non-const reference. Whereas if we code like this: `const Task & operator= (const Task &t){}`, it works without any error.

Comment: `const Task & operator= (const Task &t){}`is invalid BTW, as you forget to return.